# How do I create a vector in c++ with different row size?

Tags: c++, vector, 2d

For example, if I take n=9 inputs from the user.
inputs are = {2 3 1 1 2 5 2 7 8}
My vector should look like this:-

```
    2 3 1 1 2
    2 7 8
```

that is, a vector with 2 rows with different no. of elements in the rows. I want to skip adding 5 to my vector.
How can this be done?
Ideally it should not have any empty row. Even if two consecutive 5's occur, or the sequence starts or ends with a 5, there should not an empty row.

Comment: A vector is meant to be a 1D array, if you have multiple rows and columns, its a matrix.

Comment: So if you had multiple `5`'s, are you supposed to start a new row in the vector for each `5`?  Also, what if the sequence starts or ends with a `5`?  What should the results be?  An empty first and/or last row?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes

Comment: You haven't specified what happens if the sequence starts or ends with 5 (or even has consecutive 5's, for example: `1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7`).  Please update the question with this missing information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ideally it should not have any empty row. Even if two consecutive 5's occur, there should not an empty row.

Comment: It sounds like you need a vector of vectors.

Comment: Start small: try adding all your elements to a single vector. Then try finding a 5 while you add, and skip adding it. Then try adding half them elements to one vector, and the other half to another vectors. Build up slowly and then you're only dealing with a very small problem each time (e.g. adding items to a vector, finding an item, adding two `vector<vector<int>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions.

The first checks for the 5 and adds a row if certain criteria is met to determine if a new row is to be added.

The second solution adds a row if 5 is found, and at the end of the processing loop, erases all the blank rows.

**Solution 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> test = {2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 8};

   // Always add an initial first row
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2d(1);
   for (auto v : test )
   {
     if ( v != 5 )
         v2d.back().push_back(v);  // add value to the current last row
     else
     {
        // the value is a 5.  Check if we need to skip adding this row
        if ( !v2d.back().empty() )        

          // add a new blank row
          v2d.push_back({});
     }
   }

   // if last row is blank, remove it.
   if ( v2d.back().empty() )
      v2d.pop_back();

   // output results
   std::cout << "The number of rows is " << v2d.size() << "\n";
   for ( auto& v1 : v2d )
   {
     for (auto v : v1 )
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
The number of rows is 3
2 
3 1 1 2 
2 7 8
```

---

**Solution 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> test = {2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 8};
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2d(1);
   for (auto v : test )
   {
     // Add a new row if it is a 5
     if ( v == 5 )
          v2d.push_back({});
     else
          v2d.back().push_back(v);  // add to current last row
   }

   // remove all the blank rows
   v2d.erase(std::remove_if(v2d.begin(), v2d.end(), [&](const std::vector<int>& v) { return v.empty(); }), v2d.end());

   // output results
   std::cout << "The number of rows is " << v2d.size() << "\n";
   for ( auto& v1 : v2d )
   {
     for (auto v : v1 )
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
The number of rows is 3
2 
3 1 1 2 
2 7 8
```